# Python неверно качает zip файлы

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Не знаю в чем причина. Качаю zip файл с сервера при помощи Python, zip файл размером с 32mb, но он не хочет нормально работать, мало того что Python качает файл не весом в 32mb, а 316kb, так еще и в неверном формате!
Что делать?

[image: вот код]

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, скачивается не файл, а сама html-страница, т.к это не прямая ссылка на файл. Загрузите файл на хостинг, где есть прямая ссылка на файл и попробуйте снова.